# Android Studio - Cannot install emulator on M1

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, android-virtual-device, apple-m1, apple-silicon

I am on the latest Canary build of Android Studio (2021.2.1 Canary 3) and trying to create a Virtual Device.

When i open the AVD manager, it says at the top:

> No emulator installed.

with a `Install Emulator` button. When clicked, it says

> The following packages are not available. Package id emulator.

I then headed over to SDK Tools but unfortunately, for me, "Android Emulator" is no more listed there under SDK Tools. (Check screenshot)

I tried manually downloading the emulator from `dl.google.com/repository/.....` and unzipped the files inside `Library/Android/sdk/emulator' but no changes reflected on Android Studio.

I am not sure if this is M1 chip specific but i have tried several solutions including upgrading/downgrading/fresh-installing Android Studio but with no luck at all.

Any leads will be very helpful.

[image]